# Migrate from IBM Message broker to Apache Camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, messagebroker

My client wants to migrate from IBM products to opensource . Currently solution is running in IBM Message broker v6.1 and WAS v6. Can we migrate Message flows v6.1 to Apache Camel ?
If yes, what will be the steps and how to design the plan ?

Thanks,
Harshita

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can migrate your IBM integration platform / ESB to Apache camel.

Your existing *flows* will need to be rewritten as Apache Camel *routes*, either in XML or the Java DSL.

[Apache Camel Routes](http://camel.apache.org/routes.html)

Wherever you have an `endpoint`, such as a jms queue that you consume from or produce to, you will need to check that there is a component that can do that for you.

[Apache Camel Components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html)

Lastly, you will need some sort of container. You can either run camel applications standalone, or in some sort of container framework such as `fabric8`.

I would suggest to start with a simple proof of concept, where you rewrite one of your IBM flows as an apache camel route, and go from there.

Comment: One more query dude .. Is Fabric 8 like talend or Mule ESB ??

Comment: Yes - Fabric8 is an open source integration framework that has spawned out of Fuse Fabric, which was formerly Fuse ESB, which followed after Apache ServiceMix. I use Fabric8 and am very happy with it. (I use Mule also, both are good.